# NullPointerException on adding footer item to Android ListView

Tags: java, android, exception, listview, footer

I'm trying to make 'dynamic' listview that contains 0-2 headers and 0-1 footer(based on the needed mode).
If I use the order

```
getListView().addFooterView(footerView, null, true);
getListView().setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

I receive an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:778)
at android.widget.ListView.addFooterView(ListView.java:364)
at com.my.fragments.QuestionListFragment.updateList(QuestionListFragment.java:63)
```

and if I switch the lines to

```
getListView().setAdapter(myAdapter);
getListView().addFooterView(footerView, null, true);
```

no errors, but footer view doesn't appear on mode change (it appears on the next mode change, so I assume the code is working).

footerView is not null at this moment in the runtime

I can't figure out what is the problem here, but I really need headers and footers to be part of the listview(I can make it with a ScrollView and separate frames, but that won't do)

**Update**: A thing to add: data which is shown in the list is being loaded asyncronously and is stored in the separate static ArrayList. I use setAdapter(null) on the loading start and setAdapter(myAdapter) on complete to modify the ListView. Maybe the problem is here?

**Update2**
view_question_list_footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="2dip" android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="Load More Questions" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:lines="3" android:textColor="@android:color/white"></TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

QuestionAdapter.java

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class BrowseSettings {
        public SortingMode  sortingMode     = SortingMode.SORT_BY_DATE;
        public boolean          isAnswered      = true;
        public int              categoryFilter  = -1;
        public String           textFilter      = null;
    }

    private LayoutInflater  inflater            = null;
    private BrowseSettings  settings            = new BrowseSettings();
    private LoaderListener  loaderListener  = null;

    public QuestionAdapter(Context context, LoaderListener listener) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        loaderListener = listener;
    }

    private void loadData() {
        QAData.questions.clear();
        appendData();
    }

    public void appendData() {
        new QuestionLoaderThread(settings.isAnswered, settings.sortingMode, settings.categoryFilter, settings.textFilter,
                QAData.questions.getCount(), BaseRequest.DEFAULT_COUNT_VALUE, loaderListener).start();
    }

    public void applyCategoryFilter(int filter) {
        settings.categoryFilter = filter;
        loadData();
    }

    public void applyTextFilter(String filter) {
        settings.textFilter = filter;
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return QAData.questions.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return QAData.questions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return QAData.questions.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        QuestionViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_question, null);
            viewHolder = new QuestionViewHolder();
            viewHolder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.QuestionContent);
            viewHolder.likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.QuestionLikeCounter);
            viewHolder.question = QAData.questions.get(position);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (QuestionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.content.setText(Html.fromHtml(viewHolder.question.getFormattedQuestion()));
        viewHolder.likes.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolder.question.getLikesCount()));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class QuestionViewHolder {
        private TextView content;
        private TextView likes;
        private QAQuestion question;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the XML for `view_question_list_footer.xml` and the code for `myAdapter`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getListView().addFooterView(footerView);` instead.

Comment: How are you creating `footerView`? If using a LayoutInflater, be sure to set the parent as null: `View footerView mInflater.inflate(R.layout.footerView, null);`

Comment: footer = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_question_list_footer, null);

Comment: Why not try setting your Adapter to an empty one (i.e. a non-null object with no entries) rather than using a null value?

Comment: damn... I'm feeling like a noob :( You've made my day - empty ArrayAdapter instead of null works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: so do you managed to fix this issue setting a dummy adapter, than the header/footer view and than the real adapter? I have the same issue but I cannot fix!